# CSS issue with IE

Tags: css

Please check this:

http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/3598/ieff.png

why is it more height than in FF.. i want it to be like FF in IE

```
#message2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 105; 
    background-color: #034678;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
  height: 26px;
  width: 100%;
} 

<div class="message2" id="message2" onclick="closeNotice2()" style="display: none">
Yo, <b><? echo $pusername; ?></b> - <? echo $_SESSION["user_message"]; ?> 
<a class="close-notify" onclick="closeNotice2()">X</a>
</div>
```

When i change the size of height, It changes in FF but in IE it remains the same size..?

Comment: Does the space between `26 px` make a difference?

Comment: Yes, please cehck updated questio

Comment: Your image is cropped too tight for me to get a good idea of what's going on.

Comment: You can see the height difference in IE and FF

Comment: @Peeps is probably right. Ensure there is no space in `26px`. If you have a space, the height will be ignored in MSIE and the `div` will be the height of the containing element (which is probably taller than you want).

Comment: err. not containing element, default element. In this case your `div` I suppose.

Comment: I have no space right now, and when i change the size of it, It changes in FF but in IE it remains the same size..?

Comment: When is there ever NOT a css issue with IE?

Comment: @BillyONeal: When you use strict doctypes.

Comment: Speaking of which, can you post the entire html?  Or specifically, what doctype are you using?

Comment: If you post the entire rendered HTML (not with php code in it, but view->source in your browser), plus the entire CSS, I think the group here could have it fixed for you in about 5 mins... The information provided is tough to work with because it isn't complete.

Comment: It DOES seem odd that the text is different (spacing) in each example...are you getting a wrap due to the right side of the text being further over? almost looks like it to me, thus a width issue not a height issue.

Comment: Anther observation: you have <a... with X in it, but that does NOT show on your example...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try adding a `line-height` to your css?
Also a [css reset](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+reset) might help with the default margin and padding.

Comment: +1 for the CSS reset.  That solves 90% of cross-browser CSS sizing issues.

Comment: +1 I agree with Jacob. This will generally solve most of your CSS issues.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer has a very nasty quirks mode which activates when your web page seems to disobey the W3C standards. In quirks mode, Internet Explorer tends to render things just a (big) bit different than other browsers (to keep compatibility with older websites which where written specifically for Internet Explorer's weird rendering engine). One way to let Internet Explorer think that your web page actually conforms to the standards is to insert a DOCTYPE as the very first line in each web page.

For an XHTML web page, the doctype could be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

For a HTML 4.0 web page, it could be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: Also you should use Strict mode, not transitional.  There are still plenty of differences in browser implementations of the mentioned doctypes.

Answer (score 2):

IE will not not respect your height by default if the content overflows the container. You can add `overflow: hidden` to make it work like FireFox.

There must be some other styles affecting this. For starters, you don't show us the styles that change the color of the text, and I suspect there is styling of the link.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what your #message markup looks like. Is it an H1 or H2 or something like that? If so, you may want to reset such container styles to have margin: 0 and padding: 0. Different browsers interpret those tag-soup elements in different ways.

Comment: My #message is a <div>.., it's in the question

Comment: It wasn't in the question when I read it. You must have added it in your edit.

Answer (score 0):

internet explorer mostly has these errors when in quirksmode. do you have a valid doctype? use the w3c's validator:

http://validator.w3.org

edit:

please try to delete unneeded blanks and new-lines.

```
<div class="message2" id="message2" onclick="closeNotice2()" style="display: none">Yo, <b><? echo $pusername; ?></b> - <? echo $_SESSION["user_message"]; ?> <a class="close-notify" onclick="closeNotice2()">X</a></div>
```

Comment: please show us the complete sourcecode for further elaboration

Comment: complete sourcecode for what? all my php coding? but thats not relevant

Comment: ehmm... like between doctype and </html> :-), including all styles

Answer (score 0):

Add "overflow:hidden;" just in case the content is stretching the div and remove any whitespace between the closing div tag here and the next element in your page. Browsers should really ignore whitespace in between elements, but in practice I have found that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
zoom: 1;
```

to the css. That will sometimes make IE force the element to `hasLayout`...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE you are using? IE6 and IE8 makes a big difference, yo. Also, without complete HTML / CSS source code and/or public URL this is difficult to resolve. I would try to track down the issue using IE's Developer Toolbar, which must be [downloaded and installed](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) manually for IE6/7.

Answer (score 0):

i would try setting display:inline

Either set it on the div it self, of on the content of the div. You may need to wrap the content into another tag such as span.

But like many a person has said, you need to provide more. more code. more picutre. more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this reset with success when having issues of this nature:

[CSS reset discussion](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/01/15/resetting-again/)